# DataContarctResolver System.ArgumentException Invalid name character in '<>c'. The '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C,cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#-2.0, datacontractserializer

I am using DataContractSerializer and DataContractResolver to substitute the functionality of NetDataContractSerializer because I am porting my framework library to .Net standard 2.0 and gives me an error for not able to resolve the special character like `, <,> for the TypeName and TypeNamespace. for other tags the special characters are replaces with their respective Entity references.

I am following this to implement my Resolver`your text`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractresolver?view=netstandard-2.0

```
// Used at deserialization
    // Allows users to map xsi:type name to any Type
    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        XmlDictionaryString tName;
        XmlDictionaryString tNamespace;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(typeName, out tName) && dictionary.TryGetValue(typeNamespace, out tNamespace))
        {
            return this.assembly.GetType(tNamespace.Value + "." + tName.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Used at serialization
    // Maps any Type to a new xsi:type representation
    public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        string name = type.Name;
        string namesp = type.Namespace;
        typeName = new XmlDictionaryString(XmlDictionary.Empty, name, 0);
        typeNamespace = new XmlDictionaryString(XmlDictionary.Empty, namesp, 0);
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(type.Name))
        {
            dictionary.Add(name, typeName);
        }
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(type.Namespace))
        {
            dictionary.Add(namesp, typeNamespace);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I don't understand why special characters in TypeName are replaces with their respective Entity references. Any help would be appreciated.